# Extract Data Using Eval

Tags: javascript, regex, eval, imacros

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=ID:title  EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:acrCustomerReviewText EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:askATFLink EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\mizanrobi\Desktop FILE=product.csv
```

with above code I am able to extract 3 things

Product title: PLUSINNO Telescopic Fishing Rod and Reel Combos Full Kit, Spinning Fishing Gear Organizer Pole Sets with Line Lures Hooks Reel and Fishing Carrier Bag Case Accessories

Customer reviews: 666 ratings

Question answered: 180 question was answered among 200

what I want

for customer review and question answered I want only first number: 666 & 180 not text or any other number

and for product title: The text part before first comma (,): PLUSINNO Telescopic Fishing Rod and Reel Combos Full Kit
it can be either , or : or - so the product title will be cut off by first (, or : or -)

I know eval can help, but I can not implement.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to tag your Qt with the 'javascript' Tag as well... - Case about the Triple Separator for the 'Product title' Field is quite interesting actually, and you may want to open a parallel Thread on the 'iMacros' Forum if you don't get a Solution here from some 'regex' and/or 'javascript' Guru... - (And half of all Threads in the 'Data Extraction' Sub-Forum on that same Forum contain the/a Solution for the 2 other Fields...)

Comment: thanks a lot. I have found solution for last two just need to solve product title issue. `SET !var3 eval("var s=\"{{!extract}}\"; s=s.split(\" \");s[0];") `working find to extract desire data.

Comment: Yep, very good...!, even if I prefer a slightly different Syntax, easier to debug, the one you are using is not from me...:  -  'SET !VAR3 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var z=s.split(' '); z[0];")'  -  'PROMPT EXTRACT:<SP>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR>VAR3:<SP>_{{!VAR3}}_'  - For 'Product title', you'll need to open a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum (where I saw you created an Account yesterday) if you still need Help, I don't/rarely answer on this Forum, read my Profile... (Your Qt/OP doesn't comply (yet?) with my "Quality Criteria" anyway...)

Comment: Hum..., and stg I forgot to mention, the Syntax you are using is a bit "dangerous", and doesn't work in all Browsers supported by iMacros..., although I haven't checked/tested again since 2 or 3 years, but if I'm correct, you didn't mention your FCI, but I already know you are probably on FF, ah-ah...!

Comment: Grr..., stupid Buggy Site where Comments can only be edited for 5 min while the 'Edit' Button remains Active for 20 min..., pfff...! OK, 2nd Try...:  -  Hum..., and stg I forgot to mention, the Syntax you are using is a bit "dangerous", and doesn't work in all Browsers supported by iMacros..., although I haven't checked/tested again since 2 or 3 years, but if I'm correct, you didn't mention your FCI, but I already know you are probably on FF, and probably using iMacros for FF v10.0.2 'Free', + FF76, ah-ah...! Correct...?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I will open a new thread on iMacros Forum as I am still playing to solve the issue myself if I can not surely I will do. Yes may be the code is not all browser supported but working for my FF without issue. again thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, btw, I made a Mistake in one of my previous Comments about "that your Syntax would not be supported in all Browsers", hum, was related to some 'var s' in your 'EVAL()' that I thought you had not declared, but yep you had, and kept reusing/morphing the same var 's', which is a BAD Practice, hence I got confused.... Thus yep, your Code was OK for the Compiler, but hum... not for Help and Advice as Example to reuse for other Users, ah-ah...!

Comment: 10 days later, any Follow-up...?, or did you find a Sol by yourself...? Hum, Compliment then, I'm "nearly" Impressed...! Please share it (on this Forum), and open also a Parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum like I had asked you, or I will open it for you as your Scenario is "interesting", but it would be "handier" if you were the "Owner" of that Thread...

Comment: Got a bit "tired" of waiting, so I've created the parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum: "SOF: Extract Data using EVAL with Triple Separator." - https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=31007&p=85345# - And I've also explained one of the Solutions I had in mind...

Comment: sorry I was very much busy with something, unfortunately I found no perfect solution yet. thank you.